# C# Where with multiple values

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, where-clause

So for my current project i am trying to show all posts with the same subjects as the user add to favourites.

Now finding all posts for one subject works fine, but i want to get all.

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(x => x.SubjectID == currentUser.Favourites.SubjectID);
```

This is what i tried, but unfortunately that doesn't work, it can't find subjectID, probably because currentUser's Favourites is INumberable.
Is there anyway to compare to the multiple values that might be in the currentUser's Favourites?

Comment: So you want to check if the IEnumerable (presumably Int/String) contains the value of the Posts Subject ID like this... `db.Posts.Where(x => currentUser.Favourites.Contains(x.SubjectID));`?

Comment: Basically yes, but when i try your piece of code, the problem is that favourites itself is an object with a UserID, a SubjectID and it's own ID. So at the moment it can't compare to x.SubjectID since favourites itself is not an int.

Comment: @Wulfae: Rather than us having to guess what your code looks like, please provide enough information for us to help you. We shouldn't have to guess at the type of `Posts` or `currentUser` or `currentUser.Favourites` etc.

Comment: Sorry, not very used to asking help online normally i have someone to show trough my code. But it seems that it is working now using @Adriani6's advice.

Comment: This is what did the trick, first making a list of all subjectID's added intofav
List<int> currentUserFavouriteSubjects = new List<int>();
            var currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.username == User.Identity.Name).First();
            foreach (var favourite in currentUser.Favourites)
            {
                if (!currentUserFavouriteSubjects.Contains(favourite.SubjectID)) currentUserFavouriteSubjects.Add(favourite.SubjectID);
            }
            var posts = db.Posts.Where(x => currentUserFavouriteSubjects.Contains(x.SubjectID));
         return View(posts.ToList());

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a list of SubjectId from Favourites and then pass that list to your where clause.

```
var subjectIDs = currentUser.Favourites.Select(x => x.SubjectID).ToList();
var posts = db.Posts.Where(x => subjectIDs.Equals(x.SubjectID));
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I just did that, but your way of writing it seems better than my foreach loop

Comment: That should be `subjectIDs.Contains(x.SubjectID)`.  Using `Equals` on a `List<int>` and an `int` will never be true.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Any inside of your Where:

```
db.Posts.Where(x => currentUser.Favourites.Any(f => f.SubjectID ==x.SubjectID));
```